# Relation of KV to speed in BLDC motors

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor

The KV parameter determines the angular velocity of a motor for some voltage. I can't wrap my head around how the same supply voltage can result in different angular velocities if (I'm also unsure about whether what is say next is true) the phases of the supply are switched at the same frequency, meaning that one full revolution of the flux in stator coils takes the same amount of time independently of the KV.
I understand how lower KV and hence more coil windings result in more torque, because they generate more magnetic field, but I don't see the connection the the speed of rotation here.